# How do I run the SSH command to set StrictHostKeyChecking=no?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to run the command `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` but I'm a bit lost as to how to run it. I've tried running it from a shell script, but the output was the man page or settings that lists out all the parameters.

I then tried running that command from the shell (Cygwin) itself, but got the same man output. How do I run the command? Do I need to provide credentials or anything?

Comment: From which OS, other than Cygwin/Windows, did you try it?

Comment: I tried it on an AWS EC2 instance and got the same result. I don't have command line access to it though; the instance is spun up via datapipeline

Comment: Did you specify the target hostname? It’s a mandatory argument of the command. How does the full command line look?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: The full command line looks just like that command from the initial post. @Jakuje what I'm trying to do is edit the settings so that an `sftp` connection automatically accepts keys. On first login from a new computer, I get prompted to accept the key, but need this automated

Comment: Don’t realize what an upvote lost on the question that refers to a usage notice as “the[sic] man page or settings”, and where a mandatory argument of `ssh` is evidently missing.

Answer (score 13):

Taken from my answer on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204420/142715):

You can simply try it as it is without confitguration, just on commandline:

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname
```

but I don't think it does all what you need. If you want to ignore all hostkey checking, you need to set up you known_hosts file to `/dev/null` so there will be never anything stored:

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null hostname
```

or in `/etc/ssh_config`:

```
Host hostname
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

for specific `hostname` or you can use `*` for all host names

Comment: You may need to edit and remove a few backticks `

Comment: @Ned64 thanks. It looks like I missed some

Comment: I'm still getting the `man` results when I try this: `sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sftp.host.me -i key.pem username@sftp.host.me`

Comment: read on ;) There is more written in the answer.

Comment: Same thing. I figured it would be easier to point out that the first suggestion wasn't working

Comment: FYI to fellow Googlers, you might need the `-oHostKeyAlgorithms` flag instead, which is why this solution is not working for you. Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699192/unable-to-negotiate-with-ip-address-port-22-no-matching-host-key-type-found