# SSH authentication issue with OpenSSH private key

Tags: linux, ssh, kali-linux, openssh

I have an issue while trying to use the SSH command on my Kali Linux system (version 16.0-kali6-amd64, 2022-03-23). I'm attempting to authenticate using an OpenSSH private key.

I started by using the following command:

```bash
ssh -i id_rsa root@<ip>
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

> Unable to negotiate with  port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa, ssh-dss

After some research, I tried the following command to address the issue:

```bash
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i id_rsa root@<ip>
```

But with this command, it prompted me for a password even though I intended to use the id_rsa key for authentication.

In the verbose output, I noticed the following messages:

- "No such directory for 'load_hostkeys'"
- "DSA host key found"
- "Get agent_identities: agent contains no identities, will attempt some key (explicitly)"
- "send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm"

The authentication process then attempted to use a password and provided a prompt.

I need assistance with using my OpenSSH private key for SSH authentication.

Comment: OpenSSH since 7.0 doesn't accept hostkey ssh-dss and you must add it, similarly since 8.8 it doesn't use client ssh-rsa and you must add that with **`-oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`**. (It will still use client RSA _key_ with the newer rsa-sha2 algorithms, but your server is obviously old and doesn't support those.) See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410468/ssh-is-requiring-password-when-public-key-is-on-remote-host and cross https://serverfault.com/questions/1092998/ssh-no-matching-host-key-type-found .

Comment: What's running on the server side?  It's clearly out of date and doesn't support any modern algorithms.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Thanks for the great answer, I think this should help.

Comment: @bk2204, yes the server side ssh is older than what I have in machine.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Thank you, this solved the problem.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229124/how-do-i-run-the-ssh-command-to-set-stricthostkeychecking-no

Answer (score 48):

As mentioned by @dave_thompson, you can use additional argument when using ssh:

```
ssh -v -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa username@ipaddress
```

or another alternative, if you often access server via ssh, you can create a file named *config* in folder *.ssh*, and then add this key inside *config* file:

```
Host [ipaddress]
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

This *config* file has same result as first way.

Comment: That inline flag also works with SFTP over SSH: `sudo sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa username@ipaddress` ... I mention this because not much on Google results in regard to SFTP solutions for outdated remote servers.

Comment: in other words, the first line should read something like `Host 192.168.1.1` 

Comment: In addition to `HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`, I had to add `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` to the config. I am on macOS 13.5 connecting to my home router.

Answer (score 2):

For `Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)`:

Add one of code blocks to `~/.ssh/config`:

```bash
Host ip.ip.ip.ip
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

```bash
Host ip.ip.ip.ip
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

All works.

Comment: This works for Fedora 39 too in Feb 2024

Answer (score 1):

I had to create `~/.ssh/config` and add these lines to it.

```
Host 123.123.123.123
    KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
Host 123.123.123.123
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Comment: The second Host line is not required. I answered a question about .ssh/config that may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281876/how-many-white-spaces-is-the-best-for-ssh-config/60443212#60443212

Answer (score 1):

Just to specify the most concise way of adding more than one cipher in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host oldserver
# solve the "host key" error on ancient server
HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
# use key and eliminate password prompt on ancient server
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems connecting ubuntu with protostar vmbox.
Accomplished it running this commad:

`ssh -v -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa  -p 2222 user@127.0.0.1`

With this network config in the vmbox:
Name: SSH
Protocol: TCP
Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host Port: 2222
Guest IP: 10.0.2.15
Guest Port: 22